# Disable GTK faces in Emacs

Tags: themes, gtk3

My Emacs version is `GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.10)`.

My `region` face looks like this.

[image: region face]

Two things stand out:

1. The `region` face is unreadable.
2. The `DistantForeground` attribute seems to be set by GTK.

How can I disable this functionality, so that Emacs only uses the faces that I explicitly set through themes?